# Views and default menu block on the same page

Tags: views, blocks

I created a view to display a content type listing in a grid format. However, I cannot get the navigation menu block to show up together with this view.

This is the page using views.

[image: view page which cannot show menu block]

This is a page which does not use views. The menu block is the default generated by drupal.
[image: normal page not using views which can display the menu block]

Is it not possible to display a default menu block with a view?

Comment: No, that is for admin side, not for front end and your question unclear to me

Comment: edited my question to try to make it clearer

Comment: What region do you have the navigation block placed in? Also, just to confirm, what are the Visibility settings for the navigation block?

Comment: the navigation block is placed in the sidebar 2 region. to troubleshoot, i had made the block visible to everything.